# registerReceiver error hint " Must be one or more of type"

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-13, android-14

using
 `ContextCompat.registerReceiver(this, mIntentReceiver, filter, ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);`
or
 `registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);`

it hints "Must be one or more of: androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.RECEIVER_VISIBLE_TO_INSTANT_APPS, androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED, androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYZuB.png)

it seems i did't satisfied this option interface. and it provide tips to change to RECEIVER_VISIBLE_TO_INSTANT_APPS, if i take that, the error disappear. but this's not perfect option.

Answer (score 1):

In Sdk 34

```
ContextCompat.registerReceiver(
   requireContext(),
   smsReceiver,
   IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION),
   RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
)
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain the last parameter. Be careful about `RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED`, it's basically replacement for `registerLocationReceiver` but if want to use `registerReceiver` to subscribe for actions from not your app (like BT/ Charging and so on events) then you need to use `RECEIVER_EXPORTED` - `Specify one of RECEIVER_EXPORTED, if you wish for your receiver to be able to receiver broadcasts from other applications` from docs

Answer (score -2):

In Sdk 34 with permission

```
val intentFilter = IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION)
ContextCompat.registerReceiver(
    this,
    smsVerificationReceiver,
    intentFilter,
    SmsRetriever.SEND_PERMISSION,
    null,
    ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
)
```